# ¿Qué significa este error de RUNTIME ERROR?

Tags: delphi, pascal, firebird

estoy realizando una pantalla y cuando lo ejecuto me aparece el siguiente error, sin embargo, al darle a continuar y guardar almacena la información en la base de datos. **¿Cómo hago para quitar ese mensaje? ¿Qué me falta validar?**

[image: RUNTIME ERROR File library Unit 1: Could not convert...]

Utilizo IBExpert como manejador de base de datos Firebird.
Este es el código en Delphi que utilizo para construir la pantalla:

```
{$FORM TDescripcion, Ficha de Productos Terminados.sfm}       
uses
  Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;    

//Registrar          
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                            
  if (Memo1.Lines.Text <> '') then
    begin                
      VDESCRIPCION:= Memo1.Lines.Text;    
      Self.Close();                                      
    end                                                       
  else                   
  begin                  
    showmessage ('No puede dejar el campo vacío.');                                     
  end;    
end;   

procedure DescripcionCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (VDESCRIPCION = '') THEN 
        begin                            
        Memo1.Enabled:=true;     
        Modificar.Enabled:=false;
        Registrar.Enabled:=true;            
        Memo1.Lines.Text:='';    
        end  
   else
        Memo1.Enabled:=false;         
        Modificar.Enabled:=true;
        Registrar.Enabled:=false;                     
        Memo1.Lines.Text:= VDESCRIPCION;                                    
end;             

//Salir     
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Self.Close();  
end;              

//Procedimiento que controla los botones     

procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Enabled:=true;
    Memo1.Lines.Text:='';      
    Registrar.Enabled:=true;
    Modificar.Enabled:=false;  
end;
```

Agradezco su colaboración en la detección de la incidencia, sinceramente no encuentro como arreglarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solución:

Modifique la pantalla de esta manera para poder dar solución al problema del RUNTIME, no estaba tomando en cuenta que el valor era NULL. (Verificar el IF).

```
{$FORM TDescripcion, Ficha de Productos Terminados.sfm}       
uses
  Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;    

//Registrar          
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                            
  if (Memo1.Lines.Text <> '') then
    begin                
      VDESCRIPCION:= Memo1.Lines.Text;    
      Self.Close();                                      
    end                                                       
  else                   
  begin   
    showmessage ('No puede dejar el campo vacío.');                                     
  end;               
end;    

procedure DescripcionCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin                
  **if ((VDESCRIPCION <> '') and (VDESCRIPCION <> NULL))  THEN** 
        begin    
        Memo1.Enabled:=false;         
        Modificar.Enabled:=true;
        Registrar.Enabled:=false;                     
        Memo1.Lines.Text:= VDESCRIPCION;     
        end  
   else    
       begin
        Memo1.Enabled:=true;     
        Modificar.Enabled:=false;
        Registrar.Enabled:=true;            
        Memo1.Lines.Text:='';   
        end                                  
end; 

//Salir     
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Self.Close();  
end;              

//Procedimiento que controla los botones     

procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Enabled:=true;
    Memo1.Lines.Text:= VDESCRIPCION;      
    Registrar.Enabled:=true;
    Modificar.Enabled:=false;  
end;
```

Comment: Que bien por encontrar la causa del error. Le sugiero [edit] su respuesta para agregar el código modificado *(es decir, donde está validando que el campo no sea NULL)*. Esto es, debido a que su respuesta está en la revisión de publicaciones de baja calidad por su contenido. Usualmente estas publicaciones de baja calidad *(si no son editadas y mejoradas)* pueden ser candidatas a eliminación. Por favor lea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Listo Mauricio!! muchas gracias, espero que esto pueda a ayudar a otras personas que puedan presentar este mismo problema en el futuro!!

Comment: Ambar Vegas, gracias a usted por aportar y ser parte de la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español. Sea bienvenida de generar preguntas y respuestas en cualquier momento. Saludos.

Comment: Por cierto, después de 48 horas puedes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Al hacer esto, mejorará la calidad del sitio. Saludos.